# OPEN_PIPE_NO_AUTHORITY upon opening non-existing file using OPEN DATASET FOR OUTPUT IN BINARY MODE without FILTER

Tags: abap

I have a very strange problem.

I have a standard program with the following piece of code that tries to create a file in response to a previous attempt to open it with `OPEN DATASET ... FOR INPUT IN BINARY MODE`.

```
CATCH SYSTEM-EXCEPTIONS dataset_too_many_files = 6
                        open_dataset_no_authority = 7
                        open_pipe_no_authority = 8
                        dataset_no_pipe = 9.
    OPEN DATASET filename FOR OUTPUT IN BINARY MODE
      MESSAGE msg.
ENDCATCH.
```

Suprisingly the response to that is `sy-subrc = 8` which according to SAP documentation can happen only when `OPEN DATASET` is used with `FILTER`.

The message in `msg` variable has that `File could not be opened`, which is irrelevant because we are trying to create this file.

Did anybody experienced something like that? I suppose it has something to do with authority to create a file in a given directory on the operating system level but I cannot find any other log or trace to that. The error message and `sy-subrc = 8` seem to be actually misleading in this case. Could more pieces of information be seen by activated tracing in `ST01`?

Comment: Are you sure `CATCH SYSTEM-EXCEPTIONS` is the right way to handle errors? (it's obsolete; better use class-based exceptions). Note that `sy-subrc = 8` just means any error of `OPEN DATASET`. Is `filename` really a valid path? Did you check the OS authorizations of each folder of the path? NB: concerning `ST01`, it's for SAP authorizations, I'd better go at developer trace/workprocess log via `ST11` (eventually increase the trace level temporarily)

Comment: This is a standard program, in no way do I have influence on that and no, sy-subrc does not mean any exception in this case, at least should not mean, because they are differentiated in `CATCH SYSTEM-EXCEPTIONS`, `sy-subrc = 8` means that in case you check this after `OPEN DATASET` without using `CATCH SYSTEM-EXCEPTIONS`. Eventually thanks for the `ST11` hint, I will go this way. :)

Comment: If you create a custom test program which only does the same statement (OPEN+CLOSE), and it's successful, then maybe if you have several application servers there's one which is not configured identically, run the test program on all servers to make sure what's going on. Otherwise, contact SAP support...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the cause of the problem was in the first place the lack of the directory in which the file should be created. No wonder the system could not create the file in a non-existing folder. The error message is in such a case a misleading one anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[Open Dataset Docu](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_731_index_htm/7.31/en-US/abapopen_dataset.htm):
and
[Open datset os additions](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_731_index_htm/7.31/en-US/abapopen_dataset_os_addition.htm)

> Suprisingly the response to that is sy-subrc = 8 which according to SAP documentation can happen only when OPEN DATASET is used with FILTER.

Not exactly what the docu says. Worth another look.
Ie Would add `sy-subrc = 8` on the `open dataset`  command means

```
The operating system could not open the file.
```

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough. `8` should mean in this case `open_pipe_no_authority = 8`. It is just a coincidence that it is equal to the error code, when one does not use `CATCH ... ENDCATCH`. Hier is what documentation has on it: `Cause: Authorization for access to this file is missing in OPEN DATASET with the addition FILTER.
Runtime Error: OPEN_PIPE_NO_AUTHORITY`.

Comment: Jagger, that is exactly what I was thinking. Was it really the exception, that OS doesnt support pipes, Or was it just cant open file error.  Debug question